# DynamoDB - UpdateItem The number of conditions on the keys is invalid

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I created a Table with

1. Partition Key -> _partition_id,
2. Range/Sort Key -> _item_id

With command

```
aws dynamodb create-table 
     --table-name api 
     --attribute-definitions AttributeName=_partition_id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=_item_id,AttributeType=S 
     --key-schema AttributeName=_partition_id,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=_item_id,KeyType=RANGE 
     --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

When I try to update an Item with follwing params I get an error

```
  TableName: 'api',
  Key: { _partition_id: 'User', _item_id: 'fvmSaEmEIW' },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: 
   { '#updated_at': '_updated_at',
     '#hashed_password': '_hashed_password' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: 
   { ':H4GFZ': '2017-06-14T08:54:43.905Z',
     ':myKOH': 'xxxxx' },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #updated_at = :H4GFZ, #hashed_password = :myKOH' }
```

As you can see nothing is missing, This the error, usually this triggers if sort or partition key is missing

```
ValidationException: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid
```

Comment: The above update is working fine for me. Are you sure that it is throwing error?

Comment: @notionquest sorry it was a mistake, i found the problem, it was a hidden `deleteItem` assigned with undefined key